# Pontlyagin dual of direct sum,$ \widehat{\bigoplus_{i\in \Lambda} M_i} = \prod_{i\in \Lambda} \hat{M_i}. $

Tags: number-theory, topological-groups, duality-theorems, direct-sum

Let $M_i$ (for $i \in \Lambda$) be a family of abelian groups.

Let $\bigoplus_{i\in \Lambda} M_i$ denote the infinite direct sum of the groups $M_i$.

Let $\hat{M}$ denote the Pontryagin dual of the abelian group $M$.

I would like to know the proof that
$$
\widehat{\bigoplus_{i\in \Lambda} M_i} = \prod_{i\in \Lambda} \hat{M_i}.
$$

Any references would be appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The Pontryagin dual is a Hom $\text{Hom}(M, S^1)$ and Homs always colimits to limits. (Strictly speaking we also need to check that the topologies match but since they are both compact Hausdorff and the natural isomorphism is continuous this follows automatically.)

Comment: Some mathematicians need to be banned from creating notation 

Comment: The notation looks pretty cool, although I haven't a clue what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume the groups are discrete, as it simplifies some of the proof. Note that if you don't assume anything then you can not use the Pontryagin duality (you need at least that the groups are locally compact).

Let $\chi$ be a character of $\bigoplus_{i\in A} M_i$. For each $i\in A$, let $\varphi_i:M_i\rightarrow \bigoplus_{i\in A} M_i$ be the natural embedding (i.e. if $A=\{1,2,..\}$ then $\varphi_1(m) = (m,0,0,...)$, $\varphi_2(m)=(0,m,0,0...)$)

Then the map $\chi\circ\varphi_i \in \hat M_i$.

Now let $\varphi: \widehat{\bigoplus_{i\in A} M_i} \rightarrow \prod_{i\in A} \widehat{M_i}$ denote the map $\varphi(\chi) = (\chi\circ \varphi_i)_{i\in A}$.

We will now prove that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of topological groups.

$\varphi$ is injective:

Let $\chi$ be so that $\chi\circ\varphi_i=0$ for all $i\in A$. Let $m\in \bigoplus_{i\in A} M_i$ and write $m = m_1+...+m_k$ where $m_i = \varphi_i(n_i)$ for some $n_i\in M_i$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\chi(m) = \sum_{i=1}^k \chi\circ\varphi_i (m_i) = 0$. It follows that $\chi=0$.

$\varphi$ is surjective:

Let $(\chi_i)_{i\in A}\in \prod_{i\in A} \widehat{M_i}$, we define a character $\chi:\bigoplus_{i\in A} M_i$ by
$$\chi(m) := \sum_{i=1}^\infty \chi_i(\varphi_i(m_i))$$ where $m=(\varphi_i(m_i))_{i\in A}$. Note that this sum is in fact a finite sum because all but finitely many of the values of $\chi_i(\varphi_i(m_i))$ are zero. By construction $\varphi(\chi) = (\chi_i)_{i\in A}$.

It is left to show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. Since $M_i$ are discrete, the Pontryagin dual is compact, by Tychonoff the product of compact groups is compact. Since these groups are also Hausdorff it suffices to prove that $\varphi$ is continuous.

A basis open set in $\prod_{i\in A} \widehat{M_i}$ is of the form $U = U_{a_1}\times...\times U_{a_k} \times \prod_{i\in A \backslash \{a_1,...,a_k\}} \widehat{M_i}$ where $a_1,...,a_k\in A$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

The pre-image of $U$ under $\varphi$ is all $\chi\in \widehat{\oplus_{i\in A} M_i}$ so that $\chi\circ\varphi_{a_i} \in U_{a_i}$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$.

This is a finite intersection of the sets $B_i:=\{\chi\in \widehat{\oplus_{i\in A} M_i} : \chi\circ\varphi_{a_i} \in U_i\}$.

Since $\varphi_{a_i}:M_i\rightarrow \oplus_{i\in A} M_i$ is continuous, its dual $\widehat{\varphi}_{a_i} : \widehat{\oplus_{i\in A} M_i}\rightarrow \widehat{M_i}$ defined by $\chi\mapsto \chi\circ \varphi_i$ is also continuous. Therefore, $B_i$ is open and the claim follows.

If you want me to elaborate on something please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for constructing the concrete isomorphism maps. Your answer is excellent; I greatly appreciate it. As Qiaochu Yuan pointed out, can we prove the isomorphism (at least in a set-theoretic sense) based on the fact that Hom always commutes with limits?

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction I think he meant to say that product of groups is an example of an inverse limit of groups and direct sum is a direct limit, so $\mathrm{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i\in A} M_i,S^1) = \prod_{i\in A} \mathrm{Hom}(M_i,S^1)$. Should I elaborate on this?